# Formatting Matplotlib chart X-label in date format

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying plot my groupby object in pandas but I would like the dates to be displayed in the format 'Month - YY'. Currently, the x-axis is displaying the dates in the full date.time format which is YYYY-MM-DD.

Curent code:

```
groupby_object.plot.bar(stacked = False)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (19,8)
plt.legend(title = 'Line of Business', loc = 'centre left', bbox_to_anchor = (1,0.5)
plt.show()
```

Any idea how one can go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) to convert the datetime index to desired format.

```py
axes = groupby_object.plot.bar(stacked = False)

# Ensure your index is datetime type
groupby_object.index = pd.to_datetime(groupby_object.index)

axes.set_xticklabels(df.index.strftime('%m-%Y'))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but I get the following error: 'Failed to convert values to axis units'

Comment: @JimmyK Sorry, it should be OK now.

Comment: Thank you SO much. Has been bugging me for two days!!! Amazing!!